# Mayavi not rendering solid surface correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, vtk, mayavi

I've just re-installed Fedora 28 on my computer and decided to try Mayavi in Python 3, where it has previously only been working in Python 2.  I installed Mayavi from `pip` with `pip3 install mayavi --user` without any problems. However, when I run [this script](https://github.com/warrickball/figures/blob/master/sph_harm_mlab.py) to plot spherical harmonics, I get a surface with what looks like gaps, whereas I used to (with Python 2) get a solid surface.  I don't have the system set up for that any more but if it isn't clear what I mean, I can try to reproduce the old plots.

Any idea how to make this surface solid again?

[image: Current Mayavi window with partially transparent (or gaps in?) surface]

In case it's relevant, here's a little package info:

```
$ pip3 show vtk mayavi
Name: vtk
Version: 8.1.1
Summary: VTK is an open-source toolkit for 3D computer graphics, image processing, and visualization
Home-page: https://vtk.org/
Author: VTK Community
Author-email: vtk-developers@vtk.org
License: BSD
Location: ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
---
Name: mayavi
Version: 4.6.2
Summary: 3D scientific data visualization library and application
Home-page: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/
Author: Prabhu Ramachandran, et. al.
Author-email: prabhu@aero.iitb.ac.in
License: BSD
Location: ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: apptools, envisage, numpy, pyface, pygments, traits, traitsui, vtk
```

Comment: Surface looks smooth here. Win10 64bit, vtk 7.0.0, mayavi 4.5.0

Comment: Is it possible it comes from hardware?
(See https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/bugs.html)

I have the same kind of troubles using an intel graphic card (Intel Corporation Device 591b)

Answer (score 3):

It could be a hardware problem. 
On my laptop (under Debian GNU/Linux) I have 2 graphic cards :

- an intel graphic card
- an Nvidia graphic card with the optimus technology

To exploit the Nvidia capabilities, and because of the optimus technology, I had to install `bumblebee` (https://bumblebee-project.org/) and launch my 3D softwares using the `optirun` command :

```
optirun python3 my_mayavi_script.py
```

instead of :

```
python3 my_mayavi_script.py
```

If I try to follow the mayavi tutorial here http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html#simple-scripting-with-mlab without using `optirun`  I get

[image]

If I use optirun, I get

[image]

Comment: Do you use the proprietary nvidia driver or `nouveau`? For me, using nouveau with a Geforce GTX 660M yields the same ugly result as the intel graphics driver.